# Посчитать число Трибоначчи

Tags: java

Почти как Фибоначчи, но нужно учитывать первые 3 числа, а не два. Понимаю, что выходит за массив, но не совсем понимаю как отредактировать цикл.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = 10;
        double[] s = new double []{1,1,1};
        double[] f = new double [n];

          for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
          f[i] = s[i - 0] + s[i - 1] + s[i - 2];
          }

          for (int y = 0; y < n; ++y) {
                System.out.println(f[y]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот это `f[i] = s[i - 0] + s[i - 1] + s[i - 2];` неверно, потому что в s можно запрашивать числа от 0 до 2. А ваш аргумент в скобках выходит от 0 до 9. Где-то перепутана формула. Уже хотел предложить поменять f и s местами, но нет, ситуация с переполнением индекса при s тоже сохранится.

Comment: Нужно внимательно перечитать задание... кстати фибоначи легко считается рекурсией, возможно и тут можно применить рекурсию.

Comment: @nick_n_a циклом они считаются ещё легче, особенно если нужны все значения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int n = 10 + 3;
    double[] f = new double [n];
    f[0] = 1;
    f[1] = 1;
    f[2] = 1;

    for (int i = 3; i < n; i++) {
      f[i] = f[i - 3] + f[i - 2] + f[i - 1];
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, можете немного расписать. По какой необходимости мы первым трём числам присваиваем единицы? А что, если нам будет подаваться число `0,0,1`. Также не совсем понял про присваивание к `n = 10 + 3`.

Comment: @Blacit По той же необходимости, что у Вас написано `s = {1,1,1}`.

Comment: Да, понял, хорошо. При других числах тоже работает. Можете тогда про присваивание.

Comment: @Blacit Вам нужно посчитать 10 чисел. Три начальных - даны. Всего - 13.